# Number of integers in a list larger than a given integer possibly not in the list in log log time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

Given an unordered list of n nonnegative integers (with no guarantees about distribution or repetition), I want to be able to be given an integer possibly not in the list, and respond with the number of integers at least that large that are in the list. I have up to n^2 preprocessing time, and up to n*log(n) storage. Is this possible?

My not-good-enough solution is binary search (log n time, constant space).

Storing a map of all possible queries in a map would take up too much storage.

Edit: Partial solutions which require some assumption on the inputs, such as the distribution or max size of an integer, are also useful.

Edit: This is known as the predecessor/successor problem. There's a paper by Beame & Fich in which they construct a data structure that stores n element sets of integers from a universe of size N in O(n) space and performs predecessor queries in  O(min{(log log N) / (log log log N), sqrt(log n / (log log n))}) time.

http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~beame/papers/stocpred.pdf

Edit - Bounty: None of the answers as of this morning are exactly what I'm looking for. N is not bounded. Integers are not necessarily under 32 bits. The largest element may be much larger than the number of elements. I assume no distribution on the inputs. Of the existing answers, I accepted Coffin's for the bounty because it covers the relatively large subset of problems where I do have the distribution.

Comment: Do you have an upper bound on the size of the integers?

Comment: Also, do you need constant time, or just sublogarithmic?

Comment: Isn't this trivial? Sort in O(n log n) preprocessing time. In a map M, store a pair a[i] -> n-i for each i=0..n-1. This is O(n) time and space.  Given x, return M[x] in O(1) time.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Gene What if the query point isn't one of the elements in the list?

Comment: Your not-good-enough solution requires `n` space, not constant.

Comment: @biziclop you mean for storing a separate sorted list? I was imagining an in-place quicksort beforehand.

Comment: @DaveGalvin If you're allowed to overwrite your original data, that's different of course.

Comment: Binary search on a sorted array of integers is going to be hard to beat. Even if an algorithm requires asymptotically fewer comparisons, comparing two integers is so fast that constant factors in the more complex algorithm will almost certainly dominate until n gets extremely large. Simple bucketing (a la @גלעד ברקן) or an interpolation search might work. You should also think about splitting the data K ways on a K-core GPGPU. https://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/sortedsearch.html

Comment: @gene: parallelizing on a constant number of processors doesn't improve the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Will that's true. But maybe 90 per cent of asymptotic results in the literature are meaningless because there are asymptotically slower algorithms that perform better in practice. SO is about practical programming, not results that are of merely academic interest.

Comment: @gene: the question is clearly about improving the asymptotic complexity. For a practical implementation, I would stay away from parallel processing, which will slow down the algorithm a lot because of synchronization with the GPU. There isn't enough workload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your elements are reasonably evenly distributed (or at least follow *some* distribution fairly closely) the obvious method would be to sort the data, then use an interpolating search instead of a binary search.

An interpolating search typically has roughly O(log log n) complexity.

Oh, in case it's not obvious from the name, the basic idea of an interpolating search is to use interpolation to guess at the approximate location of the element you're searching for. If, for example, you're dealing with integers between 0 and 100,000, and you need to find, say, 21,000, you can start at a location about 21% of the way into the array instead of starting from the halfway point. Then, based on the value you find there, you can use interpolation to find a better guess, and so on.

That example is for linear interpolation, but the same basic idea applies to other distributions just as well--you just have to use a function that fits (reasonably well) with the data's distribution.

Comment: As the question states, I have no guarantees on the distribution. I'd like a solution robust to inputs chosen by someone who knows my approach and is trying to foil it. Do you think this could still work, by looking through the sorted array and somehow matching it to a distribution?

Comment: @DaveGalvin: Yes. At least from what I've seen, the first doesn't have to be particularly great to get pretty decent results, and a low-order polynomial curve fit can be quite fast.

Comment: @DaveGalvin could you say more about what you mean by "a solution robust to inputs chosen by someone who knows my approach and is trying to foil it"? Perhaps add to the problem description? Also, how large is the list/s?

Comment: @גלעדברקן All I mean here is that I don't want to make any assumption about the distribution of the inputs, which is stated in the problem.

Comment: @DaveGalvin: It's quite possible that any such algorithm will be vulnerable to attack. Consider Quicksort, for example, for which one can easily construct a worst case (see [A Killer Adversary for Quicksort](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf)). That's why many runtime libraries implement [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) or some other method that can identify pathological cases and respond intelligently. You might need to do something similar with your algorithm: implement the interpolating search, and if it begins to take too long switch to some other method.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your parameters, you could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree - "a tree data structure which implements an associative array with m-bit integer keys. It performs all operations in O(log m) time, or equivalently in O(log log M) time, where M=2^m is the maximum number of elements that can be stored in the tree."  (notice the warning at the top of the article that says there is a bug in their pseudocode)

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the space complexity for the Van Emde Boas tree? From the little I could gather from one Stanford presentation (http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs166/lectures/14/Small14.pdf) space is `O(M) = O(2^m)`, meaning a short list ranging in the billions would take up space proportional to the range rather than the list cardinality.

Comment: Suggestions for improving space consumption include http://infoweekly.blogspot.ru/2010/09/van-emde-boas-and-its-space-complexity.html which suggests using hash tables rather than straightforward table lookup in the tree nodes.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: this answer was posted before OP removed his comment to templatetypedef: "As for integer size, we can assume 32 bit unsigned.")

Prepare a hash set pointing to 65536 sorted buckets (technically, that's `O(1)` additional space, although we can say that having about 5500 elements in the list represents the threshold above which space would be less than your stipulated `n * log n`). Each key represents a possible configuration of the left most 16 bits out of your allotted 32. Each bucket will store how many elements are above the current bucket, as well as the list values in that integer range and counts of their duplicates if necessary.

At insertion, all lower bucket count-values would need to be updated; technically, an `O(1)` update time, although clearly significant for lower-sized lists; but if the list is known in advance, as you suggested, preprocessing time can be `O(n * log n)` by "reporting" the counts top-down from bucket to bucket. A query will take `O(1)` time to lookup the bucket. The lookup within the bucket could take at most `log m` where `m`, the number of elements in the bucket, is less than or equal to 65536, a constant independent of `n`.

With preprocessing, depending on the range and distribution, two or three offset hashes could be used to further optimize.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: this answer was posted before OP removed his comment to templatetypedef: "As for integer size, we can assume 32 bit unsigned.")

The `Y-fast trie` (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie), invented by Dan Willard, supports the kind of operations and time-complexity you are looking for. It uses `O(n)` space and `O(log log U)` asymptotic lookup time, where `U` is the largest value in the domain, which for our purposes could be the largest value in your list; meaning that a regular binary search with more than 32 elements in your list would already be asymptotically slower.

The Y-fast trie is constructed from `n / log U` binary search trees, which together contain the whole sorted list as a sequence; and one X-fast trie (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-fast_trie), which contains one representative for each of the binary search trees in order to lookup which tree to search in.

I'll describe a little of what I learned (because I only learned just a little) about the X-fast trie's method of successor/predecessor lookup, the operation you seem interested in. Asymptotic time complexity for the lookup is `O(log log U)`.

A lookup for the predecessor/successor of `k` starts with a binary search through the levels of the trie, which is of height `log U`. We start half way through the trie - if the prefix of `k` of length corresponding to that level is not among the trie's hashed nodes, the ancestor of `k` must be above, else below.

Once the ancestor is found, we know that one subtree of this node has leaves (leaves are where the values of the trie are stored) but the other, where `k` would have been, does not. This is where the ingenious `descendant pointer` is accessed, which points to either the smallest leaf in a right-subtree when the left-subtree is missing or the greatest leaf in the left when the right is missing.

We are now directly at either the predecessor or successor of `k` and can report the trie's stored value: which binary tree to search in. Asymptotic space complexity: `O(n + n / log U * log U) = O(n)`. Asymptotic time complexity: `O(log log U + log log U)` = `O(log log U)`

Answer (score 2):

(Note: this answer was posted before OP removed his comment to templatetypedef: "As for integer size, we can assume 32 bit unsigned.")

The Y-fast trie (see my other answer) could get us to `O(log log U + log log U)` lookup time, which means that if your range is in the billions, we are looking practically at 5 + 5 = 10 iterations per lookup.

But there is a way to achieve a practical lookup time of 5 iterations.

Hash all combinations of the left-most 17 bits. Point these 131,072 keys to X-fast tries (see my other answer) of max height 15 and max space `m * 15` where `m` is the number of elements in this particular bucket. The tries will contain only the right-most 15 bits of each appropriate element of the list. Because these X-fast tries are restricted in size, lookup time will be maxed at `1 + log 15 = 5`. If your list is under 32,768 elements, space will practically be `131,072 + n * 15`, a little more than your requested `n * log n`; but because the hash and max trie height are constant, asymptotic space complexity is actually `O(n)`, and with a list of 32,768 elements or more, space-complexity would be practically smaller than `n * log n`.

Here's a rough sketch in JavaScript of an X-fast tree:

```js
function pad(width, string, padding) { 
  return (width <= string.length) 
         ? string 
         : pad(width, padding + string, padding);
}

function makeXFastTree(elems){

  var xfast = {};
  var height = Math.floor(Math.log2(Math.max.apply(null, elems))) + 1;

  function insert(x){
    var y = pad(height,x.toString(2),'0');
    var l = 1;
    var d = y.substr(-l,1);

    // add element to the parent node
    if (!xfast[y.substr(0,height - l)]){
      xfast[y.substr(0,height - l)] = [y,y];
    } else if (d == '1'){
      xfast[y.substr(0,height - l)][1] = y;
    } else {
      xfast[y.substr(0,height - l)][0] = y;
    }

    // update higher nodes
    l++;
    d = y.substr(-l,1);
    var temp = y.substr(0,height - l);
    while (temp.length > 0){

      if (!xfast[temp]){
        xfast[temp] = d == 0 ? ['0',y] : [y,'1'];
      } else if (d == '0'){
        xfast[temp][0] = '0';
        if (xfast[temp][1] != '1' && y > xfast[temp][1]){
          xfast[temp][1] = y;
        }
      } else {
        xfast[temp][1] = '1';
        if (xfast[temp][0] != '0' && y < xfast[temp][0]){
          xfast[temp][0] = y;
        }
      }

      l++;
      d = y.substr(-l,1);
      temp = y.substr(0,height - l);
    }
  }

  for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
    insert(elems[i]);
  }

  return [xfast,height];
}

function find(T,height,x){
  var y = pad(height,x.toString(2),'0');
  var l = d = height >> 1;
  var temp = y.substr(0,l);

  while (true){
    // ancestor found
    if (T[temp] && !T[y.substr(0,temp.length + 1)]){
      return T[temp];
    }

    d = Math.ceil(d/2);

    if (T[temp]){
      l += d;
      temp = y.substr(0,l);
    } else {
      l -= d;
      temp = y.substr(0,l);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```js
var t = makeXFastTree([31,27,10,5,4,2,1]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(t[0]));

{"0":["0","1"],"1":["11011","1"],"11":["0","1"],"110":["11011","1"],"111":["11111","1"]
,"1101":["11011","11011"],"1111":["11111","11111"],"0101":["01010","01010"]
,"010":["01010","1"],"01":["0","01010"],"0010":["00100","00101"],"001":["0","00101"]
,"00":["0","1"],"0001":["00010","00010"],"000":["0","1"],"0000":["00001","00001"]}

console.log(find(t[0],t[1],28));

["11111", "1"]

console.log(find(t[0],t[1],3));

["00010", "00010"]
```

Comment: `posted before OP removed his comment to templatetypedef: "As for integer size, we can assume 32 bit unsigned` - which was before adding `Partial solutions which require some assumption on the inputs, such as the distribution or max size of an integer, are also useful`.

Comment: @greybeard That does not seem too relevant to me. Considering that I got to learn something new, I probably won't hold a grudge for too long, but I'm a bit peeved that the OP posted a bounty for a significantly different question, which I spent quite a lot of time thinking about. Had I known, I would have thought differently about how to possibly contribute.

Answer (score 1):

If the preprocessing time and space are enough to put the data in a tree, you could create a sorted tree where every branch stores how many leaves are connected to its right (greater-than) side. While constructing the tree, this count can be incremented for every branch you pass on the right when inserting a new leaf, so it doesn't take (much) extra time. Getting the number of values greater than or equal to a certain integer can then be done by finding the place of the integer in the tree, and adding all the counts of the branches you pass on the left on the way.

The time complexity would be the regular complexity of the tree type plus a few value increments per leaf during construction, and the space would be the regular space plus a counter for every leaf, the size of which depends on the maximum number of leaves.

In the example code I used a simple binary tree; you could use leftover preprocessing time to height-balance the tree (making sure the counts are updated), or use some kind of self-balancing tree type (but that would probably prove overly complicated).

Example code snippet in Javascript: (uses 100,000 random integers; handles duplicate values and search values that are not present in the tree correctly)

```js
function ChopTree() {
    this.root = null;

    this.insert = function(value) {
        var branch = null, leaf = this.root, before;
        while (leaf != null) {
            branch = leaf;
            before = value <= leaf.value;
            if (before) leaf = branch.left
            else {
                ++branch.count;
                leaf = branch.right;
            }
        }
        if (branch == null) this.root = new Leaf(value)
        else if (before) branch.left = new Leaf(value)
        else branch.right = new Leaf(value);
    }

    this.chop = function(axe) {
        var branch = this.root, count = 0;
        while (branch != null) {
            if (axe <= branch.value) {
                count += branch.count;
                branch = branch.left;
            }
            else branch = branch.right;
        }
        return count;
    }

    function Leaf(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.count = 1;
    }
}

var t = new ChopTree();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) t.insert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4294967296));

document.write("Inserted 100,000 random integers from 0 to 2<SUP>32</SUP><BR><BR>");
document.write(t.chop(0) + " greater than or equal to 0<BR>");
document.write(t.chop(2147483648) + " greater than or equal to 2<SUP>31</SUP><BR>");
document.write(t.chop(4000000000) + " greater than or equal to 4&times;10<SUP>9</SUP><BR>");
document.write(t.chop(4294967296) + " greater than or equal to 2<SUP>32</SUP><BR>");
```

Update: incrementing the count value could be used to handle duplicate values, if you expect a lot of those and space is an issue.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs request to improve on `O(log n)`, regular binary search, lookup time?

Comment: @גלעדברקן It probably doesn't. I just wanted to try out the idea and throw it out there, maybe someone can improve it. Without more details about the number of values and the number of lookups, it's hard to tell. I think the N^2 preprocessing time allows for tree-building; after that it depends on the tree depth; it's probably never going to beat your 5 iterations Y-fast trie.

Comment: Feel free to downvote; I don't have the peer pressure badge yet.

Comment: Lol. I don't like to downvote, I just asked out of curiosity. I've noticed other good/interesting answers you've posted.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Cheers. Would I be right in thinking that the tree construction would be n*log(n) and a lookup log(n), similar to the OP's not-good-enough solution? (I never studied CS so I don't know much about complexity calculation.)

Answer (score 1):

With integers limited to 32 bits, the question doesn't make much sense. Indeed, if N is less than 2^32, then it is bounded and asymptotic complexities do not make sense.

If N is unbounded, then you can sort the values and in linear time count their multiplicities. This way, the number of elements is bounded again and asymptotic complexities no more make sense.

Something is flawed in the problem statement.

Comment: What elements are bounded in number after counting, and what would constitute such a bound?

Comment: So now I can read a bound, without an explicit statement _what_ is bounded by it - number of counts? With N unbounded, I know no more than that the number of integers to represent the counts is O(NlogN).

Comment: @greybeard: right, with unbounded N, the counts must be unbounded as well :(

Comment: Integers aren't limited to 32 bits. I never said they were.

Comment: @DaveGalvin: I must have misunderstood your comment "As for integer size, we can assume 32 bit unsigned" then. What did you mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust How foolish of me. You are, of course, right. I forgot about that comment. The issue is that partial solutions are still useful to me, so while I want a solution that makes no assumption about the max size of an integer or the distribution of the inputs, solutions that do have these constraints are useful in some cases. I have removed the offending comment so the question is now clear.